# how to get selected text, but can I get surrounding context in javascript?

Tags: javascript, selectedtext

I am able to grab the text that a user has selected on a web page,
using this code:

```
function getSelected() {
  var userSelection;
  if (window.getSelection) {
      selection = window.getSelection();
  } else if (document.selection) {
      selection = document.selection.createRange();
  }

}
```

is it posible for me to get the words *around* the
selected word.

Take these sentences for example: "If you need to
framglubble the zartbox, then you should buy the red widget.
Otherwise you can buy the blue widget and save some money."

My code will tell me if the person has selected the word "widget".
But I'd like to know if the selection is after "red" or "blue". Is
this possible? I've been scouring the Internet for some advice, and
I'm having trouble finding an answer.

thank you for your help

Comment: @James Wiseman: I was going to vaguely answer something like "possible in IE only" and "use the `move("word", +-1)` method but expect your page to break with a large portion of users".  But ranges are completely new to me.  If you know a better way, I'm interested myself here.

Comment: @user495688 - your questions are good and valid but I second James opinion that you should Accept answers, that's how this place is operating.

Comment: i'm sorry,i'm forget to check the answer..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written quick script that can identify the part before selection and after selection inside the same DIV element.

However if the same DIV contains the same word more than one time and you select only that word, the current code I wrote can't identify if it's the first or second selected word so bottom line it will not answer your needs.

Anyway, you can see/copy/test the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/kvHxJ/ just select something and see the alert that appears.

If it's enough for your needs after all then great, accept this answer and move on... otherwise I need to know: **can we assume the user will select whole words only, one word only?** If the answer is yes I do have idea how to go around this.

Comment: I assume that the user akam choose one word, then I get the words before and after the word selected. but the words are limited to 20 words only, that is 10 words before and 10 words after or can be flexible if the word before it only contains 5 words then be taken after 15 words.

Comment: is it possible to identify the part before and after selectiion in different DIV/paragraph??

Comment: @user495688 - still not sure if the code is enough or if you must also support more than one same word in same paragraph. Regarding "part before and after selectiion in different DIV/paragraph" it won't be easy - can't you control the design of the text?

Comment: yes indeed, I have to get 20 words around the word selected.
eg in the first paragraph there are 5 words that 15 words could of the rest in other paragraphs. what is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this in non-IE browsers is to obtain a [`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range) object from the [selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/selection). The range has a start and end boundary, and each boundary of the range is expressed as an offset within a node; if the boundary is within a text node, this offset will be a character offset.

For example, if the following was a text node and the selection is delimited by pipes:

```
"red |widget| blue widget"
```

... then the range you'd get from the selection would have a start offset of 4 within the text node.

The following will get you a Range representing the selection and alert the start boundary:

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
var selectedRange = sel.rangeCount ? sel.getRangeAt(0) : null;
if (range) {
    alert("Offset " + selectedRange.startOffset
        + " in node " + selectedRange.startContainer.nodeName);
}
```

Ranges may be compared to other Ranges, so if you wanted to know, for example, if the current selection came after the word "blue" in the above text node, you could create a Range encompassing the word "blue" and compare it with the selected Range:

```
// Assume the text node is stored in a variable called textNode
var blueRange = document.createRange();
blueRange.setStart(textNode, 11);
blueRange.setEnd(textNode, 15);

var selectionIsAfterBlue =
   (selectedRange.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.END_TO_START, blueRange) == 1);
```

In IE, none of this works and everything is done differently, generally with much more difficulty. To normalize this to single consistent interface, you could use my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) library.

Answer (score 0):

IE has the `move` set of methods, which reduces this problem to just a couple of lines to expand the selection forward or backward any number of words (see http://www.webreference.com/js/column12/trmethods.html).  From there, it's just a matter of comparing text against any arbitrary list of values.  Other browsers don't have this feature AFAIK.  Fate of the browser wars: one develops an awesome feature ignored or barred by patent from any other, so the feature is forever lost and avoided as burden of cross-browser support for all these innovations inevitably falls squarely on the website designers.

So, below is a generalized function to only get the ID of the parent element of the selected text.  And, to work with this cross-browser solution, you have to wrap each word in it's own element complete with unique ID or other attribute.  With this setup, it should then be a relatively painless jump to looking ahead and back at sibling or sequentially ID'd/named elements.

The catch here is that the client has to click/drag from the start of the word or phrase to the end, and absolutely no bordering spaces.  Even double-clicking on a word will cause it to reference the next element (or in the case of IE, the parent DIV).  Additionally, you should add code to restrict the selection boundary to a single parent DIV, as the below code may also expand the selection to surrounding elements.  But hopefully you can take fixing that up from here.  Otherwise, it's up to using vectors to pinpoint the coordinates of a text compared to all surrounding text.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function get_selected_element_id() {
 if (window.getSelection) {
  // FF
  var range = window.getSelection();
  }
 else if (document.selection) {
  // IE
  var range = document.selection.createRange();
  }
 if (range.focusNode) {
  // FF
  var test_value = range.focusNode.parentNode.id;
  }
 else {
  // IE
  var test_value = range.parentElement().id;
  }
 return test_value;
 }


</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="test_div">
 <span id="test1">test</span> <span id="test2">asdf</span> <span id="test3">test2</span> <span id="test4">bla</span>
 </div>

<button onclick="alert(get_selected_element_id());">go</button>
```